# Replace duplicated values with a blank string

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'a':'Male','c1':3,'c2':10},{'a':'Male','c1':3, 'c2':30},{'a':'Male','c1':1,'c2':20},{'a':'Female','c1':2,'c2':15},{'a':'Female','c1':2,'c2':100}])
```

I want to print the bellow:

```
   a      c1   c2
0  Male   3    10
1              30
2  Male   1    20
3  Female 2    15
4             100
```

Would you please help me?

Comment: Please add a description of your desired result, I'm guess you want to null the duplicated values

Comment: Please provide code snippet of your current progress as a place to start.

Comment: Please don't update your question with changing requirements, you should state upfront either your real data or representative data relevant to your question, it's very poor form on SO

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if you literally want a blank string or `NaN` but I'm using `NaN` here, you can test if a column has duplicated values using [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.duplicated.html#pandas.Series.duplicated) and set these to your desired result, by the way you need to add an explanation of what your desired result means rather us guess:

```
In [128]:
df.loc[df['c1'].duplicated(), 'c1'] = np.NaN
df

Out[128]:
   c1   c2
0   3   10
1 NaN   30
2   1   20
3   2   15
4 NaN  100
```

The blank string version:

```
In [131]:
df.loc[df['c1'].duplicated(), 'c1'] = ''
df

Out[131]:
  c1   c2
0  3   10
1      30
2  1   20
3  2   15
4     100
```

**EDIT**

You updated your question so I've updated my answer:

```
In [143]:
df.loc[(df['a'].duplicated() & df['c1'].duplicated()), ['a','c1']] = ''
df

Out[143]:
        a c1   c2
0    Male  3   10
1              30
2    Male  1   20
3  Female  2   15
4             100
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lots but but would you please see my question again?

Comment: Sorry, If 'a' and 'c1' both are duplicated than it will be ' ' ,Otherwise not , please see you again my output template ...